# How mature is Azure CLI 2.0 compared to Azure Powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-cli2

With reference to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45585000/1431250), how mature is Azure CLI 2.0, can all Azure powershell functionalities be achieved using Azure CLI?

Comment: `can all Azure powershell functionalities be achieved using Azure CLI?` - Have you done the comparison yourself?

Comment: Azure Cli 2.0 is design for ARM mode. So, you could not use it to manage classic resource. But, Azure powershell can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Cli 2.0 is design for ARM mode.  It does not support classic mode. Azure Power Shell support ARM mode and classic mode.

> can all Azure powershell functionalities be achieved using Azure CLI?

The answer for ARM mode, almost all PowerShell functionalities could be achieved using Azure CLI 2.0.

Comment: @Abhijeet Hi, please let me know if you would like further assistance.